# Apply transtion/animation effect to <details> element when it's closing

Tags: html, css

I'm trying add transition effect to `details` element on opening and closing:

```css
details
{
  height: 1em;
  transition: height 2s;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
}

details[open]
{
  height: 6em
}
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>summary</summary>some
  hidden
  text
</details>
```

When it opens, it slowly expands, revealing the hidden text, but when it closes it hides the text instantly then slowly shrinks. I'd like it to hide the text by shrinking.

Is there a way achieve that in CSS only?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are [out of luck](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) with that right now.

> Unfortunately, at this time, there's no built-in way to animate the
> transition between open and closed.

If perfect animation is a big deal for you, you will need to roll your own accordion using generic elements like `<div>`. Even doing it this way there are still limitations, such as the inability to animate between `height: 0` and `height: auto`.